# Google Analytics underestimating pageviews and visitors

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Very few visitors on Analytics: incorrect setting?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16074/very-few-visitors-on-analytics-incorrect-setting)

Google Analytics reports are underestimating pageviews comparing to my server logs for around 40%. What could be the reason? Browsers not allowing cookies?

Also webmastertools tells me that I get 400 to 500 vistis through google search engine per day, but GA tells me that there are only 250 visitors from googlesearch.

Comment: Do you discount prefetches/prerenders?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics also does not track most search spiders, other known bots, and of course anybody that does not have JS enabled. All combined that can account for quite a bit of traffic sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you have your Analytics tracking inputted as having `http://www.yourdomain.com`  or just `http://yourdomain.com` and whatever your forcing the redirect or not for users could effect the traffic shown through Analytics.

So if some users are only putting in `http://` and you don't have that tracking and your not forcing a redirect from `http://www.` to `http://` your losing hits.

Hope this helps!